# List filename of match when file matches string (modifying this code)

Tags: perl, filenames

I created a script for scanning all word documents in a directory. The problem that I ran into was that I can match with regular expression, but I have no idea which files the matches are coming from. I can print the entirety of the file that the matches are coming from by using `$file` inside of `foreach my $file( $string)`, but want to only get the filename from that file. Entering `__file__` give the filename of the script itself and not the file. This is probably an easy answer, but I am currently stuck.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

 use strict qw/refs/;
 use warnings FATAL => 'all';
 use Text::Extract::Word;

 binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

 my $file = glob('*.doc');
 my $extractor = Text::Extract::Word->new($file);
 my $string = $extractor->get_text;

 my $count = () = $string =~ /the/g; 

 print "there are ".$count." matches"."\n";

 foreach my $file( $string)
 {
     print "Matches correspond to the following file(s): ".""."\n";
 }

 close STDOUT;
```

Comment: The `glob` function returns an array of files.. You assign only first file to `$file`..

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the `glob` function [perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) :

> glob EXPR
>
> In list context, returns a (possibly empty) list of filename
>   expansions on the value of EXPR such as the standard Unix shell
>   /bin/csh would do. In scalar context, glob iterates through such
>   filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted. This
>   is the internal function implementing the <*.c> operator, but you can
>   use it directly.

So you could try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Extract::Word;

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

for my $file (<*.doc>) {
    my $extractor = Text::Extract::Word->new($file);
    my $string = $extractor->get_text;
    my $count = () = $string =~ /Hello/g; 
    print "there are $count matches in file '$file'\n";
}
```

Comment: I'd rather say `glob` is an iterator function. It has a defined behaviour in scalar context where it doesn't return a list (and doesn't use the standard conversion from list to array). Also, in perl nothing returns arrays. Return values are either lists or references to arrays.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. Thanks!.. updated answer with more accurate description.

Comment: That is so awesome :) I was trying to do something originally without using glob, but couldn't get it right. This is perfect!